# vstest.console.exe does not return any exit code

Tags: c#, vstest, vstest.console.exe

**Problem**: I'm running vstest.console, but it is not showing any exit code. below is the command that I'm running.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console" Testing.dll
```

**Output**: Part of the output is the below text, but I'm expecting an error code to find out whether the tests have passed or failed. example: 0 error code, if there are no failures and non-zero if there are failures

Test Run Failed.
Total tests: 100
Passed: 50
Failed: 50
Total time: 2 Minutes

**Question:** what can I do to get an exit code from vstest.console.exe

Comment: The source code is publicly available, so no better place to dig than GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/tree/main/src/vstest.console

Comment: Use the %errorlevel% environment variable.

Comment: how do you check error code ?